# Can neo4j acces CSV file with basic HTTP auth from remote URI when using LOAD CSV?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Can neo4j access CSV file with basic HTTP auth from remote URI when using LOAD CSV?
ex : 
`LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "http://user:passwd@host:port/file.csv"`

Answer (score 1):

As far as i am concerned there is no way to pass auth credentials

If you control the httpd machine you can do the following:

Set up a server on a different port.
The way i have it set up is via a private IP (both neo, and the httpd machine are on the same private network) That way there is no need for auth, and no one outside of the private network can access the httpd.